# jQuery div serialize restul is empty string

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a div (form) that I want to serialize using jQuery but the result is an empty string.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="rakebackForm" class="wrapper wrapper-white">
    <div class="page-subtitle">
        <h3>RakeBack New Record</h3>
        <p>Please enter all the information requested.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><span>Start Date</span></label>
                <input name="StrStartDate" type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><span>End Date</span></label>
                <input name="StrEndDate" type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <span>Amount</span></label>
                <input name="Amount" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> <span>Site</span></label>
                <input name="Site" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

and this is my jQuery code:

```
 var form = $('#rakebackForm');
                        var data = form.serialize();
```

> Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** with form or form elements, and use jQuery **[`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)** pseudo selector to get form elements

```
var form = $('#rakebackForm :input');
var data = form.serialize();
```

Comment: Great it works!! what about if I want to serialize other element that is not "input"?

Comment: @VAAA : iterate over them and generate the array , `map()` can be use

Comment: Use `:input`  pseudo selector  instead of `input` to include other form controls